# What replacements are available for vbscript in an application?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, embedded-language

An application I maintain has been around since VB6 days - ported to .Net 1.1, and now being updated/rewritten across to .Net 3.5

The application provides a mechanism to run VBScripts - this was done in a highly integrated way - allowing the program to parse multiple .vbs files and produce a list of all of the subroutines and functions - which were then available within the application alongside core functions.

Previously this was an embedded msscript.ocx - in the first .Net conversion, this was wrapped in Interop.MSScriptControl.dll, however, on Windows 7 this just isn't working.

It looks like this is really not the way to be doing this anyway - Microsoft seem to be trying to kill vbscript.

Is there a 'supported' way of using VBScript, or is it time to move on? and if so, where is there to move to that provides the same sort of functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) is the really the way you want to go if you want to do scripting.  Here are some of the new features in [PowerShell on Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd367858(WS.10).aspx).  Here is a [VBScript to PowerShell conversion guide](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/winpsh/convert/default.mspx).

There are also tons of great resources over at [PowerShell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/) including a nice [IDE](http://www.scriptinternals.de/new/product/powershellide.zip).